# Why do char * and char ** have the same value?

Tags: c, pointers

I have written this code which is simple, 
So what I do not understand is why `**str1` and `**str2` are the same?

***Code***

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *str1 = "Hey, you";
    char *str2 = malloc(11);
    strcpy(str2, "Hey! You");

    if (*str1 == *str2) {
        printf ("HoHoHo!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*str1` is the first `char` of the array pointed to by that pointer, it's not a `char**`. This compares the first character of the strings, which both contain the same thing. You may have been thinking of `if(&str1 == &str2)`.

Comment: Because both are `*(char*)'H'`. Which is not making any sense, yet the same.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No they aren't. They're both `'H'`.

Comment: @Barmar `*strx` are `'H'`. `**strx` are not.

Comment: But `**strx` doesn't appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Barmar Then I guess it is a typo, but a consistent one. Given the title, it is even more confusing.

Comment: @Barmar no only in the question, which is right the code or the question? It's tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Nowhere in your code do you have `**str1 and **str2`. I guess you are asking why is this true `if (*str1 == *str2)`? That code tests the *character* pointed to by `str1` and `str2`. Since that's is `'H'` in both cases the expression evaluates to true.

If you want to compare C style strings you use `strcmp` which returns zero if two strings are equal.

```
if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
{
    printf ("HoHoHo!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`str1` points to "Hey, you".

`str2` points to "Hey! you"

`*str1` is the `char` *at that address*. Which is essentially the first letter of the string: 'H'.  The first letter of str2 is also 'H'.  Hence `(*str1 == *str2)` is a true expression because ('H' == 'H')

To compare two strings:

`strcmp(str1, str2)` - returns 0 if the same contents, non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

the `*` before the symbol means something completely different in the declaration and in the function body.

`int *x;`  - declares the pointer to the `int` object

`y = *x;` - the `*` dereferences the pointer `x` it is the opposite to its meaning in the declaration. It takes out one level of indirection, when in the declaration it adds one level.

I think that is reason of your confusion.

in your example `if (*str1 == *str2)` the `*` "removes" indirection and the result is the char itself (not the pointer to pointer)